# How to go to "APP for Sharepoint" page sharpoint online

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, spfx

I have developed an spfx webpart and i need to upload the same in sharepoint site. Could please guide me how to go to that "Apps for sharepoint" site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean that you want to upload web parts to app catalog?

[image]

If so, you have to prepare an App Catalog site collection:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/use-app-catalog